# Pandas groupby transform to get not null date value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe constructed as so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],
                   'birthdate': ['01-01-01','02-02-02','03-03-03','04-04-04',
                                 '','02-02-02','03-04-04','04-03-04']})
df['birthdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['birthdate'])
```

I want to do a groupby to change the original data using pandas `.transform`

The condition is that I want to pick the `birthdate` value of the first not null row per `id`

I know I can do `max` if no other option is available to get rid of the not null entries, but if there are inconsistencies, I don't necessarily want the maximum date, just the one that occurs first in the dataframe.

As such:

```
df['birthdate'] = df.groupby('id')['birthdate'].transform(max)
```

This is how output looks using `max`:

```
id  birthdate
0   1 2001-01-01
1   2 2002-02-02
2   3 2003-03-03
3   4 2004-04-04
4   1 2001-01-01
5   2 2002-02-02
6   3 2004-03-04
7   4 2004-04-04
```

This is how I actually want it to look:

```
id  birthdate
0   1 2001-01-01
1   2 2002-02-02
2   3 2003-03-03
3   4 2004-04-04
4   1 2001-01-01
5   2 2002-02-02
6   3 2003-03-03
7   4 2004-04-04
```

I'm pretty sure I have to create a customer `lambda` to put inside the `.transform` but I am unsure what condition to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following. Your dataframe definition and suggested outputs contain different dates, so I assumed your dataframe definition was correct

```
df['birthdate'] = df.groupby('id').transform('first')
```

which outputs.

```
   id   birthdate
0   1   2001-01-01
1   2   2002-02-02
2   3   2003-03-03
3   4   2004-04-04
4   1   2001-01-01
5   2   2002-02-02
6   3   2003-03-03
7   4   2004-04-04
```

Comment: You're right. Had a typo in the output. Thanks for catching that. Also, yes... this solves it! So first works regardless of the position of the null value. That is interesting. Awesome!